# Problem on position of bookmarks in PDF

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, bookmarks

I am writing a book that has 3 parts and each part has many sections. After compiling the `.tex` file, some of the bookmarks of the `.pdf` file are misplaced as shown in below:

[image]

and its MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\author{A}
\title{B}
\begin{document}
 \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \part{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \part{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \part{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
\end{document}
```

Whats wrong? Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: I think this happened because you missed `\chapter{...}`. `book` document class expects the following hierarchy: part → **chapter** → section → subsection → ...

Comment: I know this priority. but I don't want to use chapters.

Comment: You could change to article which does have parts and sections but no chapters…

Comment: @C.F.G:  You could use the `bookmark` package, that 'sanitizes' the bookmarks and keeps the levels in order, but actually, omitting chapters is an logical error!

Comment: Omitting the chapter will also lead to section numbers like `0.5` showing up, which is awful.

Comment: ... and the section number is never reset, if that is what is wanted .... forgot that in the comment above....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hierarchy of levels (that's why it is called level) in `book` class, is with their associated numbers, starting from top to bottom

> part (-1) - chapter (0) - section (1) - subsection (2) - subsubsection
>   (3) - paragraph (4) - subparagraph (5)

Omitting one level is a logical error that confuses `hyperref`. Either do not omit `chapter` or use the `bookmark` package that cleans up the wrong leveling.

A third method involves reassigning the level numbers for the bookmarks, i.e. there is a `\toclevel@X` which `X` standing for one of the above mentioned levels.

Please note, that this does not cure the problem that the sections appear with a `0` as prefix in the section number and section numbers are never reset this way (since the chapter counter is not stepped).

Summary: The proper way is to switch to `article` or including `chapter` as **sectioning** level.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\toclevel@section}{0}
\renewcommand{\toclevel@subsection}{1}
\renewcommand{\toclevel@subsubsection}{2}
\renewcommand{\toclevel@paragraph}{3}
\renewcommand{\toclevel@subparagraph}{4}
\makeatother
%\usepackage{bookmark}
\author{A}
\title{B}
\begin{document}
 \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \part{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \part{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \part{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
\end{document}
```

[image]